# What does this 'single' value represent in gradient?

Tags: python, tensorflow, input, keras, gradient

I tried to calculate gradient of output layer w.r.t. input and i am expecting a matrix of gradient (as gradient of different nodes in output layer w.r.t. each input) but i am getting a single value. I want to know what this value represent here?

My aim was to calculate gradient of categorical-cross-entropy loss w.r.t to each input. I was searching for a solution and then i stuck at this.

I am new to this, so please ignore silly mistakes.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras import backend as k
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=1, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, init='uniform', activation='softmax'))

outputTensor = model.output
listOfVariableTensors = model.input

gradients = k.gradients(outputTensor, listOfVariableTensors)

trainingExample = np.random.random((1,1))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
evaluated_gradients = sess.run(gradients,feed_dict={model.input:trainingExample})

print(evaluated_gradients)
```

I got output of print statement as:

```
[array([[0.]], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: What's your version `tensorflow` and `keras`? My return is `[array([[0., 0.]], dtype=float32)]` on `tensorflow=1.12.0` and `keras=2.2.4`.

Comment: @giser_yugang Thanks......Mistakenly i pasted code for input_dim=2...Question is valid in any case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`k.gradients` is a wrapper that actually runs `tf.gradients`. 
As described in the document

> Constructs symbolic derivatives of **sum** of ys w.r.t. x in xs.

The result of `tf.gradients` is the sum of all `ys` derivatives of `xs`. The formula is as follows:

[image]

The shape of the result is the same as that of `xs`, not `ys`. An example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1.],[2.]])
b = tf.matmul(a,[[3.,4.]])
c = tf.matmul(a,[[5.,6.]])

grads1 = tf.gradients(ys=b,xs=a)
grads2 = tf.gradients(ys=[b,c],xs=a)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(grads1))
    print(sess.run(grads2))

[array([[7.],[7.]], dtype=float32)]
[array([[18.],[18.]], dtype=float32)]
```

Just do `tf.gradients(ys=loss,xs=input)` if you want to calculate the sum gradient of categorical-cross-entropy loss w.r.t to each input.  You'd need to call `tf.gradients` for each `ys[i,j]` separately if you want to calculate gradient of different nodes in output layer w.r.t. to each input.